# Understanding aggregate_array

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get a list of NDVI values as calculated for each image in an ImageCollection for a given point. This list will then be matched to a list of dates for the point, to produce an array of values. However, when I use aggregate_array it only collects 54 values, and not the 100 in the ImageCollection. Could anyone shed some light on this? The code is below:

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([-96.17,18.17])
var start = '2017-01-01'; //start date Sentinel 2
var end = '2018-12-31'; //final date Sentinel 2

function maskOutClouds(img) {
  var mask = ee.Image(0).where(img.select('QA60').gte(1024), 1).not();
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

function addNDVI(img) {
  return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference([('B8'), ('B4')]).select([0],['NDVI']));
}

var imgs = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate(start, end)
                                              .filterBounds(aoi)
    .map(maskOutClouds)
    .map(addNDVI)

print(imgs)

var imgsDate = imgs.map(function(image){
  return image.set('Date', ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
})

print(imgsDate,'imgsDate')
var list = ee.List.sequence(1,imgs.size())

var dateList = ee.List(imgsDate.aggregate_array('Date'))
print(dateList)

var dateNDVI = (imgsDate.select(['NDVI']))
print(dateNDVI,'dateNDVI')

var NDVIprop = dateNDVI.map(function(image){
  return image.set('NDVI', (image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), aoi, 30)).get('NDVI'));
})

print(NDVIprop,'NDVIprop')

var NDVIvalue = function(ndvi){
  return ndvi.get('NDVI')
}


var NDVIdateSel = NDVIprop.filter(ee.Filter.inList('Date',dateList))
                          .filterBounds(aoi)
print(NDVIdateSel,'NDVIdateSel')

var NDVIdateSelAdd = NDVIdateSel.map(function(ndvi){

  return ndvi.set('NDVI',(ndvi.get('NDVI')))

})

print(NDVIdateSelAdd,'NDVIdateSelAdd')


var NDVIlist = NDVIdateSel.aggregate_array('NDVI')
print(NDVIlist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, this is because in 46 of your images, the pixels in the ROI have been masked. possibly when you masked for cloud.
You can check how many pixels you are working with by using this

```
Map.addLayer(NDVIdateSelAdd.count(),{min:0,max:100});
```

Because of this there are 46 images that have NDVI = **null** which does not appear in the response of **aggregate_array**

Edit: you can also check this using aggregate_histogram instead to check if there are some common numbers. In this case though we will see 46 images with **null**.

Comment: Thanks! It had occurred to me that masking the clouds may set the band values to null (or 0, which would result in a 0 in the denominator in the NDVI calculation), which explains why there is no NDVI property in those 46 images.